# Multiple unnest

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
select moi.ORDERNO,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(itemdetails,'itemId\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\",')) as sku,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(itemdetails,'mrp\\\\":(.*?),')) as mrp,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(itemdetails,'discountPrice\\\\":(.*?)}')) as discountedprice,
-- ITEMDETAILS
from `CUSTOMERS.MEDICINE_ORDER_INVOICE` moi 
limit 100
```

Item details is of the form

```
"[{\"itemName\":\"Colgate Super Rakshak Toothpowder, 100 gm\",\"itemId\":\"COL0129\",\"batchId\":\"B02A1/H\",\"issuedQty\":3,\"mou\":1,\"mrp\":60,\"isSubstitute\":false,\"discountPrice\":0},{\"itemName\":\"Colgate Super Rakshak Toothpowder, 100 gm\",\"itemId\":\"COL0129\",\"batchId\":\"B23/H\",\"issuedQty\":1,\"mou\":1,\"mrp\":62,\"isSubstitute\":false,\"discountPrice\":0}]"
```

The error I am getting is unexpected keyword unnest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should flatten an array in `FROM` clause in BigQuery, not `SELECT` list clause.

```sql
with `CUSTOMERS.MEDICINE_ORDER_INVOICE` as (
  select 
  -- put *itemdetails* sample data here
  as itemdetails
)
select sku, mrp, discountedprice
  from `CUSTOMERS.MEDICINE_ORDER_INVOICE` moi,
unnest (regexp_extract_all(itemdetails, r'itemId\":\"(.*?)\",')) as sku with offset o1,
unnest (regexp_extract_all(itemdetails, r'mrp\":(.*?),')) as mrp with offset o2,
unnest (regexp_extract_all(itemdetails, r'discountPrice\":(.*?)}')) as discountedprice with offset o3
 where o1 = o2 AND o2 = o3;

-- query result
+---------+-----+-----------------+
|   sku   | mrp | discountedprice |
+---------+-----+-----------------+
| COL0129 |  60 |               0 |
| COL0129 |  62 |               0 |
+---------+-----+-----------------+
```